# 4 Ubuntu servers each w/ 4 NICs into 4 switches into 1st router to a 2nd router: can not ping 2nd router

Tags: networking, routing

BACKGROUND: Servers numbered 100, 101, 102, and 103. NICs numbered 20, 30, 40, and 50. For example, the second server's third NIC has address `192.168.40.101/24`. The first router's addresses are 254 for each port supporting each of the four networks, plus another for upstream to second router. Servers running Ubuntu 18.04 and using NetworkManager.

The first router is an 8 port Ubiquiti model. The second is a cable modem with access to the internet. The second router has an address of `192.168.0.1/24`. As the first router has all 5 networks physically connected to it (`192.168.0.0`, `192,168.20.0`, `192.168.30.0`, `192.168.40.0`, and `192.168.50.0`) the routing table on the first router is fairly straightforward with 5 directly connected entries and one static route for `0.0.0.0` next hop `192.168.0.1` (2nd router).

The `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` file is patterned off of "Configuring Source Routing" from Netplan Examples on internet. DHCP4=NO.

PROBLEM: I can ping the first router from server 100 but not the second router. I can ping the second router from the first router. Playing around with this, I can get either "network unreachable" or no response from the ping (playing with the gateway4: specification in the YAML file). Note: per guidance I only have one gateway defined. For the case where gateway is defined as `192.168.20.254` for `eth0` and the ping hangs, I think the return packets are not finding their way back.

What have I missed? I thought the multiple NIC based routing tables with routing policies would address this multi-NIC problem, but it hasn't.

Here's the network diagram:
[image: Network diagram]

Comment: Have an honest doubt troubleshooting network design questions are on topic here. These kind of questions without a drawing/diagram are not easy to visualize and answer.

Comment: Can you draw up a simple diagram to help us visualize your problem as Rui suggested.  And/or try to rewrite your question with the fact that we are not familiar with your setup in mind.

Comment: Hi, your ubiquiti is the gateway for those 5 subnet ? Can I ask why it jump tru the router 2 for the default route ?

Answer (score 0):

It was something relatively straightforward after all. Sharing with the community in case it might be helpful to others.

The second router is a cable modem router provided by my internet provider. It has one private IP address on the WAN side and NATs all traffic to the 192.168.0 network on the LAN side. It has no ability to know about other networks as best I can tell. I could play around with port forwarding and maybe get this to work but I decided against this. The solution to my problem was to replace my 192.168.10 network on my servers with 192.168.0 so they are participants on the one network known by the cable modem. Its not want I wanted, but the solution ultimately is to get more private IPs from my service provider with a different cable modem at a greater monthly cost. I'll get there in time, but for now, the solution I implemented is workable.

Here's a diagram:
[network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCZjk.png)